# Omniauth, mongoid, pure omniauth, authentication tries to insert twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, omniauth

So I'm building a webapp using mongoid and pure omniauth. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/2013/10/rails-4-twitter-omniauth-with-mongodb/) but I'm running into an issue where mongodb is trying to insert the same record twice and throwing a duplicate key error. Is there any way for me to figure out where the second insert is coming from?

Here is the code from the sessions controller:

```
def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = User.where(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid']).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to user_path(@user), :notice => "Signed in!"
end
```

This is the code in the user model for create_with_omniauth

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth['provider']
    puts "finish provider"
    user.uid = auth['uid']
    puts "finish uid"
    if auth['info']
      user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ""
      puts "finish name"
      user.email = auth['info']['email'] || ""
      puts "finish email"
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      puts "made oath token"
      user.save!
      puts "Saving the user"
    end
    puts "outside if"
  end
  puts "about to exit"
end
```

So in the server logs I see finish provider, finish uid, finish name, finish email, made oath token, an insert, then Saving the user, outside if, and about to exit, and then another insert. But from the code in sessions controller my user use either queried or created. I don't see where I would be doing another insert.

Thanks!

Edit: Added code

Answer (score 1):

The way you usually debug stuff is to either go through the invocations step by step - you can use REPL for this, like [PRY](http://pryrepl.org/). Another option is just to do binary elimination - start of at some point in your code and make sure if the issue is before or after that point, move your next breakpoint in that direction and then just repeat this until you have narrowed down the cause.

Overall it's very hard to help you out unless your provide code that is not working or just give more information. Right now you are saying "something is wrong, what is it", without anyone else knowing what "something" is or what "wrong" means. You just won't be able to get any useful help this way.

Comment: Good suggestion on adding code. I did put lines to print to the server in between each step to see where things were happening and attached the code along with what I saw from the server in my post. Is that enough to give an idea of what I'm trying to do?